# Getting csgo skin screenshot off cs.money

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Anyone got any luck requesting cs.money screenshots from an inspect link?

Tried this but end up getting `{"error":5}` as a response. Request matches the one that is made on site upon requesting a screenshot and from an old reddit post, csgo_ses and steamid cookies should be enough

```py
def get_screen_id(inspect_link):
    m = re.search('A(.+?)D', inspect_link)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
        return found

def get_screen_links(csm_id):
    data = {"item":{"id":csm_id},"isBot":False,"botInventory":False,"isInGame":False}
    r = requests.post('https://cs.money/screenshots', json=data, cookies={"csgo_ses":my_csgo_ses_cookie, "steamid":my_steam_id})
    return r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is a security error.
Your request is missing some security headers, csrf tokens or some cookie.